# Locking mechanism in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

I want to implement a lock mechanism so only one thread can run a block of code. 
But I don't want other threads to wait on lock object, they should do nothing if it's locked. So it's a little different than standard lock mechanism.

```
if (block is not locked)
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

What is the best way to do this in C#.

Comment: One thread within the application or one thread within the same system/OS (eg. crossing multiple instances of the same application)?

Comment: Can't you just use a boolean value for that?

Comment: @Tarec: how is it supposed to be thread-safe?

Comment: @Hans Passant: it's obviously (from the question text) that instead of "block is not locked" OP in fact meant "obtain lock if possible, go to else otherwise"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then instead of using locks, you should use the [`Monitor` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx).

[Excerpt: Monitor.TryEnter() example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx)

```
// Request the lock. 
if (Monitor.TryEnter(m_inputQueue, waitTime))
{
   try
   {
      m_inputQueue.Enqueue(qValue);
   }
   finally
   {
      // Ensure that the lock is released.
      Monitor.Exit(m_inputQueue);
   }
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

As [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) noted, `waitTime` can optionally be zero.  Depending on different scenarios 10ms or 100ms might be more effective.

Comment: As a side note: `waitTime` *can be zero* if the OP doesn't want any waiting at all

Answer (score 0):

use `Monitor.TryEnter( lockObject, timespan)` { .... }